# PostgreSQL vs MS SQL Server compatibility with java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have to design a Java Application, which has database connectivity as well. I am unable to decide which database should i use? "PostgreSQL" or "SQL Server 2008". I want to know which has better compatibility with Java language? Also which one is more easy to use and implement?

Comment: IMHO it totally depends on Your own comfort level with the respective DBMS.!!
And then comes the cost (if DB is going to be more than 4GB in case of  SQL Server)

Answer (score 3):

This is a very subjective question and one that will likely be closed, but for what its worth, this is my opinion:

Both database servers are compatible with Java using JDBC and several ORM's such as Hibernate.

Instead of Java compatibility what you need to consider is:

- Your resources (financially and computationally)
- Your familiarity with one DBMS over another

SQL Server tends to be a bit of a hog for installation. For management tools your looking at SSMS, which can be a bit of a beast, but is very good at what it does.

PostgreSQL is lighter on the installation front. The PgAdmin III tool is very effective at what it does, and is, in my opinion, easier to use.

SQL Server's free editions have database limitations. It's paid versions do not, but they are expensive. PostgreSQL does not have any limitations for database size, and it's open source.

Both DBMS's have a vibrant community and help is readily available.

Hope this helps.

--Edit--

As a starting point for databases, each database server will be as easy as any other to learn on; although the tools that the server provides may temper the learning curve some.

Should I have to go back to square one and relearn everything again, heres what I would do:

- Pick PostgreSQL. I would chose PostgreSQL to learn on as it is fully ACID compliant, has little tolerance for syntax errors, and provides exactly what you ask for in the result sets.
- I would learn the command line utilities first, followed by PgAdmin III as it would give me the best possible exposure to the database, without holding my hand.
- Read the documentation found on [PostgreSQL.com](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/) and supplement questions with Stack Overflow, and dba.stackoverflow.com
- DON'T PANIC. Learning a DBMS is a tall order, one that I have yet to complete. There are times when it is frustrating and hard. It will be easy to want to quit. Don't. Hang in there and keep trying, the rewards are worth it.

The PostgreSQL community is great, and the answers I have gotten, and seen on other posts here on SO are top notch. For some samples, check out any answer by a_horse_with_no_name and Erwin Brandstetter, I guarantee you will learn something.

Comment: Said the same thing :D :P
Still upvote for detailed explanation. (Y)

Comment: thanks!!!!     'lkhlhlhlhlhlhllhlhllh

Comment: No problem. If the question is answered, please hit the checkmark beside the question. If it is not, please clarify any unanswered points so we can continue helping :)

Comment: @RobertH ,, i am not sure what to say, em not familiar with any of these, I had been using access uptil now~ ,,, So,, dont know what to do, will it be easy to use any of them or not, which is more easy,, whose tutorials are readily available? etc etc, ALL these questions are arsing in my mind!